# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Error message

Tags: xcode, constraints

Can someone help me debug this error message code? I am fairly new to Xcode development. I looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html) on Apple Documentation,  but still after spending time, I am not able to find out what is causing the issue. All I have is a collection view. I haven't configured any elements inside the Collection View yet.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6080000980b0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840.width == 148   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000098880 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840.height == 79   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000907c0 UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0.width == 1.875*UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000093420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000092e30 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095db0 H:[UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098100 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7ff8f1c3f9e0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7ff8f1c3f840 )>"
```

Image of my storyboard here 
[image]

I am using Xcode 8

Comment: I can't help unless you provide more context to the question. Are you using storyboard? Try posting a screenshot of it.

Comment: As the error says, you have conflicting constraints, post the constraints of your collection view. Make sure you don't have something like; fixed width = x, then anchor to the left and right with Y which could be the cause of this.

Comment: I am using storyboard. I have listed the constraints here.